# Python map() function iterates over 'None' element

Tags: python, list, nonetype, map-function

I wrote a simple map() function that iterates over a list and prints as many '*' that are in the list. I see a small problem with my code, I see an extra `'None'` in my output. Could someone help me debug this issue?

```
Problem Statement:
-----------------
Define a procedure histogram() that takes a list of integers and prints a
histogram to the screen. For example, histogram([4, 9, 7]) should print the
following:

****
*********
*******
```

Source Code

```
def print_asterisks(num):
    print ''.join('*' for i in xrange(num))

def histogram(s):
    map(print_asterisks, s)

def main():
    # Test inputs
    print histogram([4,7,5])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output

```
****
*******
*****
None
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
print histogram([4,7,5])
```

You are printing the return value of the `histogram` function, which is `None`.  You only need to call the function:

```
histogram([4,7,5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the function `histogram` isn't returning anything. `print histogram([4,7,5])` prints `None`.

```
def print_asterisks(num):
    print ''.join('*' for i in xrange(num))

def histogram(s):
    map(print_asterisks, s)

def main():
    # Test inputs
    histogram([4,7,5])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
****
*******
*****
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
def main():
    # Test inputs
    print histogram([4,7,5])
```

with

```
def main():
    # Test inputs
    histogram([4,7,5])
```

Note: the function `histogram` doesn't have any return statement.

Answer (score 1):

write histogram([4,7,5]) instead <strike>print histogram([4,7,5])</strike>

```
def print_asterisks(num):
    print ''.join('*' for i in xrange(num))

def histogram(s):
    map(print_asterisks, s)

def main():
    # Test inputs
    histogram([4,7,5])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```